# How to call a function from a different view controller with different classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nscoder

When you press on the screen im trying to get a function that Is in a different view Controller to be called usaully i would just do the
     viewControllerFuncIsIn().NameOfFunc()
but because the view controller class that has the function im trying to call is a SCNView. it gives me this error with ns coder because in currently in a Skscene
[image]
the function im trying to call is in a class called Extra1 right below the viewdidload(not in it).

Update for comment below:

```
 Extra1(coder:NSCoder())!.see()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read or googled the error? You are trying to use the init method `init(withCoder coder: )` without passing in a coder

Comment: yes i get an error ill update my code now @Simon McLoughlin

Comment: Try to use delegates or notifications

Comment: @Hunter If you don't have a NSCoder to pass in, then create a new init that doesn't take in any parameters

Comment: OK ill try to search delegates or notification and calling functions

Comment: and ok ill try give me a sec

Comment: i add my answer try to use delegates and that notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small example for you:

**Use delegate when connection is one to one.**

Delegate:

Create protocol:

```
protocol TestViewControllerDelegate {
  func finishTask(sender: TestViewController)
}
```

Create reference for delegation. It should be weak it is important.

```
weak var delegate:TestViewControllerDelegate?
```

Exited you're class.

```
extension MainViewController: TestViewControllerDelegate {
  func finishTask(sender: TestViewController) {

  }
}
```

Call delegate:

```
delegate?. finishTask(self)
```

**Use notification when connection is one to many.**

Notification:

Add observer for notification.

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ClassName.test), name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Post notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Comment: ok cool but theres an error i cant fix on weak var delegate:TextViewControllerDelegate? it says weak may only be applyed to class and class-bound proticol type, not 'TestViewControllerDeleggate' and itll just keep saying that know matter where i put that line of code @Oleg Gordiichuk

Answer (score 0):

I fond the answer to my question

```
func mySelector(elem: AnyObject) {
    Extra1().see()
}

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.mySelector), name: "see", object: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("see", object: self)
```